# .NoSuchElementException on click of the submit button, working with SelctOneMenu in JSF1.2

Tags: jsf

I have a jsf page with few input components and two h:selectOneMenu components.

On selection of a value in the first drop down I'm calling a valuechange listener and submitting the form. Then I populate the value into the other drop down depending on the value selected from the first drop down. Now I enter other fields and click on the submit button.

It throws me the below mentioned exception.

My Backing bean is in Request scope. I hope it will work fine for me if I change it to session bean which is not right to do in my application. I'm populating the data to SelectItem variable from the "ValuechangeListener" method.

JSF version is 1.2, I can't upgrade it to 2.0 at this point.

Comment: please give us the code for your html file, a wild guess is that any of your id is wrong because jsf generate your id to something else

Comment: You don't even mention the actual exception!

Answer (score 0):

RequestScope in this case is not enough. You need at least ViewScope.

This is because the Bean will get reset with every request. The listeners of your Bean will be called for another instance of that bean and will change that. After that you do some changes in the browser and the next time you send a request, your bean has already been destroyed. Thus everything you did in your listeners got lost and that's why you run into problems.

If you work with ajax, or stay on the same page and keep manipulating it, then you should switch to a higher scope.

Comment: at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
 at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
 at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at javax.faces.component.SelectItemsIterator.next(SelectItemsIterator.java:98)
 at javax.faces.component.SelectItemsIterator.next(SelectItemsIterator.java:124)
 at javax.faces.component.UISelectOne.matchValue(UISelectOne.java:141)
 atjavax.faces.component.UISelectOne.validateValue(UISelectOne.java:114)

Comment: Does this still occur after you have changed to @ViewScope? If so then something is wrong with the logic of your code. This exception occurs if you have a List<SelectItem> which has not a single entry. I think you cannot have a dropdown with 0 options.

Comment: Yes your right this error was because List<SelectItem> without values.After changing it, I was able to fix the issue. Thank you for your support and sorry for the late reply.